# Getting JSON response instead of XML from Google cloud storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am using the code given below to get response from google cloud storage service :

[Php Google cloud storage](http://code.google.com/p/google-storage-php/source/browse/trunk/GoogleStorage.class.php)

By using the above code i get an XML response but, i want a JSON response. Please tell me how to do that?

Are there any headers that i need to set??

Or certain parameters? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the JSON API, you need to request access via the Google developer console.  Currently the JSON API is in limited preview release.